# Is there any API for presenting normalized data after a query is made from linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

For example [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) does this to with the Northwind database:

```
http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers/ALFKI?format=html
```

Is there anything that reads the database structure and relationships and output a report based on a primary id?

Obviously, I am looking into alternatives to servicestack.

Comment: LINQPad actually allows you to do something like this. The nice thing is that you can even import your own assemblies, so you can test out LINQ queries using production code and display the results in the window. You can also display intermediate results by calling `Dump()` at any stage of the LINQ query (as long as you're in method syntax, not sure how it works in query syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use LINQPad's .Dump() object visualizer for that. Download LINQPad from http://www.linqpad.net and reference the .exe in your project.

You will then have access to LINQPads .CreateXhtmlWriter() that can output a beautiful object graph visualization:

[image: LINQPad .Dump() example]

just by going:

```
var listOfItems = DataContext.Items.ToList();

listOfItems.Dump();
```

The following is not my code, but I cannot find the origin, so bear with me.

Use extension method to create the Xhtml dump and show it a browser:

```
public static class LinqPadExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes object properties to HTML 
    /// and displays them in default browser.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="o"></param>
    /// <param name="heading"></param>
    public static void Dump<T>(
        this T o,
        string heading = null
    )
    {
        string localUrl =
            Path.GetTempFileName() + ".html";
        using (
            var writer =
                LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter(true)
        )
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(heading))
                writer.Write(heading);
            writer.Write(o);
            File.WriteAllText(localUrl, writer.ToString());
        }

        Process.Start(localUrl);
    }
}
```